# Android get battery design voltage

Tags: java, android, battery

Is it possible to get the design voltage of the battery in android programmatically? So that I can calculate the watts for the battery?
I just found the current voltage in the android documentation.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also need current to calculate power...

Comment: But I want to calculate the cost for charging my phone ones...So I thought I need mAh * Volts.